# Cannot remove InfoPath form form central admin

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, infopath

I have an Admin Approved InfoPath form deployed as a feature on SharePoint 2010 farm. After deployment i can see the form in Manage Form Templates and i activated to a site collection. I wanted to make changes to the form and tried to upload the new form to the CA. I cannot remove/update the form even after deactivating the feature. 
When I try to upload the updated form it says 
**Form with the same identity urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:infopath:formname is already deployed on this farm.**. 
If I try to upload the form with upgrade option(replace if existing) it says -
**The following form template cannot be upgraded because it is not currently uploaded on this farm: urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:infopath:formname**
If i try to remove it says -
**This form template was deployed as part of the  feature.  This form template should be removed only by uninstalling that feature.**

Answer (score 0):

Go To -> Site settings ->Site collection Administrators ->Site Collection Features, in the list you will see a feature that maps to the name of the XSN file.

Click on the Deactivate button and in the query string the feature GUID is shown, copy it and don’t deactivate the solution.

Then run an STSADM command:

```
stsadm -o uninstallfeature –id <the feature GUID you got from the query string> –force
```

Check the [reference](https://spandps.com/2012/08/01/infopath-the-following-form-template-cannot-be-upgraded-because-it-is-not-currently-uploaded-on-this-farm-sp2010/).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had been through this article earlier and it did not work for me.